# Istio: Retrieving certificate details of another pod

Tags: istio

I'm trying to understand how mTLS is implemented in Istio and came up with the below scenario.
In my setup I have a namespace foo with two pods as below:

```
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
httpbin-75b47445c9-gscrn   2/2     Running   0          1d
sleep-6777b55c98-tlqb6     2/2     Running   0          1d
```

My requirement is to retrieve the public certificate of `httpbin` from `sleep`.(*Just for testing purposes*)

So I get an interactive shell inside sleep and execute the [below](https://serverfault.com/a/749381/229473) command.

```
curl --insecure -v http://httpbin.foo:8000/ip 2>&1 | awk 'BEGIN { cert=0 } /^\* SSL connection/ { cert=1 } /^\*/ { if (cert) print }'
```

But I'm not getting any output from it.

However, if I replace `http://httpbin.foo:8000/ip` with `http://google.com` I can get the certificate details correctly.

Can you please explain what is happening here.

Comment: Are you able to get anything from http://httpbin.foo:8000/ip?

Comment: @Crou No. when I try to ping it I get `ping: bad address 'http://httpbin.foo:8000/ip`. When I do `curl -v http://httpbin.foo:8000/ip` I get a `200 OK` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that when you run `curl http://httpbin.foo:8000` from an Istio-injected pod, the following happens:

1. Your HTTP request arrives to the Istio sidecar proxy of your pod (`sleep`)
2. The sidecar proxy encapsulates your request into mTLS connection to httpbin.foo:8000
3. The sidecar proxy of `httpbin.foo` performs TLS termination (decapsulates the original HTTP request) and forwards it to the `httpbin.foo` service
4. The `httpbin.foo` service receives the original, plain HTTP request
5. The `httpbin.foo` service sends a plain HTTP response
6. The sidecar proxy of `httpbin.foo` encapsulates the response and returns the response to your sidecar proxy
7. Your sidecar proxy returns the response back to your curl

Note that your curl will get plain HTTP response of the `httpbin.foo` service, which is unaware of Istio mTLS. Istio mTLS is like a tunnel for the communication between your curl and `httpbin.foo`, the certificate from the tunnel will not be returned to your curl.

To get the certificate of the sidecar proxy of `httpbin.foo`, you need to send a request to `httbin.foo` service directly (it will arrive to the sidecar proxy of `httpbin.foo`), bypassing the Istio sidecar proxy of your source pod (`sleep`).

For that you can deploy the `sleep` pod to some namespace without Istio injection, and then use `openssl` to retrieve the certificate:

```
kubectl create namespace without-istio
kubectl apply -f samples/sleep/sleep.yaml -n without-istio
kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -n without-istio -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name}) -n without-istio -c sleep -- openssl s_client -connect httpbin.foo:8000
```